# extract token from curl result by shell script

Tags: json, shell, curl, token

I write this script

```
#!/bin/bash
# cm.sh

  curl -i \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '
{ "auth": {
    "identity": {
      "methods": ["password"],
      "password": {
        "user": {
          "name": "admin",
          "domain": { "id": "default" },
          "password": "secret"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}' \
  "http://localhost/identity/v3/auth/tokens" ; echo



echo $tokenizer1 
echo $tokenizer2
```

But all of them(awk or sed) it's the same

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   540  100   312  100   228    312    228  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  5142
```

My goal is to put the token in a variable for later.
Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: I reopened this because it's not about parsing JSON but instead HTTP headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the direct result of cURL, you could save the result in a file, and use your grep command on it.
Something like this maybe :

```
curl -o boulou.txt http://localhost/identity/v3/auth/tokens && cat boulou.txt | grep "X-Subject-Token" | awk '{printf $2}'
```

Edit, if you just want you desired output, add the `--silent` to the cURL command :

```
curl -o boulou.txt http://localhost/identity/v3/auth/tokens --silent && cat boulou.txt | grep "X-Subject-Token" | awk '{printf $2}'
```

Edit 2: If you want to export it, and delete your file, you could use something like this :

```
export OS_TOKEN=$(curl -o billy.txt hhttp://localhost/identity/v3/auth/tokens --silent &&  cat billy.txt | grep "X-Subject-Token" | awk '{printf $2}') && rm billy.txt
```

Comment: I updated my response @Khalfe telle me if you need some more things

Answer (score 0):

"How do I use grep/awk to extract a header in a field from curl when I pass it a JSON document when the contents is stored in a variable?" is a very tricky and unique problem indeed.

However, if you gradually mock out every part of your code to narrow it down, you'll discover that this is the much easier question you could have researched or asked instead:

> #### How do I use grep/awk on contents from a variable?
>
> I have a variable containing HTTP headers, and I want to extract the value of one of them. Here's an example:
>
> ```
> variable='Foo: 1
> Bar: 2
> Baz: 3'
> ```
>
> This is what I've tried to get `2` from `Bar`:
>
> ```
>   # Just hangs
>   tokenizer1=$variable `grep "Bar" | awk '{printf $2}'`
>   # Is empty
>   tokenizer2=$variable | `grep "Bar" | awk '{printf $2}'`
> ```

The answer here is to use `echo` to pipe the contents so that grep can read it on stdin:

```
tokenizer3=$(echo "$variable" | grep "Bar" | awk '{printf $2}')
```

This is easily applied to your example:

```
tokenizer3=$(echo "$token" | grep "X-Subject-Token" | awk '{printf $2}')
echo "The value is $tokenizer3"
```

Comment: `awk '/Bar/ { print $2 }'` -- no need for a prior `grep`.