# Extracting access token from curl request in shell script

Tags: shell, curl, jwt, sh

Using a postman as a base, I have a curl request here and I'm trying to return the access token.

```
AUTHORIZATION=$(curl --location --request POST 'https://some.url/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=$GRANT_TYPE" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET"\)
```

When I `echo` I get an output like:

```
{"access_token":"16WkRKbVpHWXlZekJsWVd...","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":14400}
```

I want to extract the `access_token` and use in other parts of my script. I've tried the adding `jq .access_token -r` as seen below, but I'm just returning a `null` variable.

```
AUTHORIZATION=$(curl --location --request POST 'https://some.url/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=$GRANT_TYPE" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET"\
-s \
| jq .access_token -r)
```

Solutions here: [extract token from curl result by shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147598/extract-token-from-curl-result-by-shell-script) advise saving to file and grepping on it. I don't really want to save a token to a file if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you flipped the parameter name and value when calling jq. I think it should be:

`jq -r .access_token`

not `jq .access_token -r`

Other than that your solution looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Save the response in a variable

```
AUTHORIZATION=$(curl --location --request POST 'https://some.url/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=$GRANT_TYPE" \
--data-urlencode "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" \
--data-urlencode "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET"\)
```

Step 2 use jq.

```
AUTHORIZATION = `jq '.access_token' <<< "$AUTHORIZATION"`
```

Step 3 eliminate the quotes.

```
AUTHORIZATION=`echo "$AUTHORIZATION" | tr -d '"'`.
```